# WCF Authentication over REST

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-security

I've been researching this now, on and off, for weeks and found no real, concrete solution as of yet - so I wondered if I can spark up some ideas on how other people get around this, if at all.

**Scenario**

- Website calls WCF Service via AJAX (via WebAPI acting as a proxy, or
  directly, same end result).
- Website wants the results back in JSON format.
- Website and WCF Service may not sit on the same box, so cross-domain.
  I understand WebAPI can be used here to combat that, but, it's not
  always possible.
- WCF Service should **only** be called from that singular Website (or
  a website with authentication details), I don't want any bots
  spamming it for data.

Simple, right? Wrong.

**Main problem**

- Basic authentication - Solves all problems, right? Nah, if you're
  going cross-domain you have to use JSONP to get JSON results back, in
  which you can't modify the request headers and thus not being able to
  send through authentication details in a header. Using
  http://test:test@url.com doesn't work in some major browsers (IE) and
  neither does CORS.

OAuth, could be a solution? The problem I have with this is that, if a user isn't logging into the website, then how is there going to be a two-way handshake that any other website can't simply just take the API key sent in the query string to the service? And, if there is a password with the API key, it's still just sent as clear text? Am I misunderstanding this process and is it viable for my scenario?

I saw this which looked promising: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/372422/Secure-WCF-RESTful-service-using-OAUTH

But, the end part of it shows the service still being called server-side, rather than through jQuery.

Please, please, for me and probably thousands of others out there in the same boat, is there a solution out there?

**UPDATE**

In the end, I did actually end up using: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/372422/Secure-WCF-RESTful-service-using-OAUTH and going down the OAuth route to authenticate between requests. The code-behind work simply injects the parameters and signature values into JavaScript variables on the page and sends these via an AJAX request to the service. It now works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a service on site A which you want to access from a website on site B? And the requests from B to A need to be authenticated?

You could then implement a proxy on site B that makes authenticated calls to the service on site A. This authentication can be in any form, but basic auth + HTTPS is feasible. Or take a look at client certificates. You have to configure this once and it shouldn't have to change. Now nobody can access the service on site A, except when they have the basic auth credentials or the client certificate (or other credentials that you supplied).

Then from the website on site B you issue requests to the proxy on site B, which redirects the request to the service on site A, using the (serverside) configured credentials.

If you want everyone to be able to call the proxy on site B from the website on site B, even when not logged in on the website, but from nowhere else, you could let the website create a token (serverside), which is registered with the proxy. Then if the website issues a request to the proxy, it sends its token. A token could be valid for a limited amount of time or requests (perhaps even one request).

Comment: I thought about doing this (WebAPI acting as a proxy). However, it still would be, in URL terms, http://site/api/ExampleCall, in which anyone could access. There's no login to the site, so how do you distinguish between "good" and "bad" users who are accessing this URL to gain data? You always have to have a HTTP URL for jQuery to make a call to, and it's this call that should be locked down, Proxy or no Proxy.

Comment: The last paragraph, in terms of tokens, is that basically what OAuth does?

Comment: @thedixon you'll have to have your Javascript client, which does the request, to append the token to the request. This can be done in the URL (`&token=123abc`) or in an HTTP header field ([`(X-)`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6648.txt)`Token: 123abc`). You can then read this token in your proxy. I do not know much about OAuth, so I can't answer that.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer, for your time and effort. I've updated my answer though for others to see what solution I did use.

Comment: No clients generally are "unauthenticated" - every client (website/app) has to have an authentication key in order to access the service.

Comment: @thedixon then you haven't solved this part in your question: _"The problem I have with this is that, if a user isn't logging into the website, then how is there going to be a two-way handshake that any other website can't simply just take the API key sent in the query string to the service?"_ - am I right?